# What is needed to develop ArcGIS application in C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I want to develop a piece of software that uses the ArcGIS Engine. This application needs to import user data (GeoTIFF, etc) and allow users to put points and polygons on a map. I would think this would be VERY straightforward.

I am unable to find sufficient detail on how to begin this process and was hoping someone here could help me.

There are APIs, there is the ArcGIS Engine, there is ArcObjects, also SDKS. I don't know which I need to develop my application. I would love to make a Windows Form application in C#.

What would I need?

Do I need ArcGIS Engine?

I am working on computers that have ArcGIS desktop installed.

How can I know what else is installed (Engine, Objects, etc...)?

How can I get ArcEngine if that is what I need?

Comment: For what you've described you would need to have ArcEngine and the ArcObjects SDK for Microsoft .Net Framework installed.  These programs should show up in the list of installed programs if they are installed.  If not, they would need to be purchased and licensed as these are definitely not free.

Comment: Okay, great.  My computer has ArcGIS Desktop.  If I understand correctly, that license can be used for ArcEngine as well?  If that is the case, how do I get ArcEngine on a machine that already has ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Now that I look at it I think you might be right. And I don't think you have to actually install ArcEngine.  When you install the SDK (which is definitely a requirement) you will be able to create a project in Visual Studio that utilizes ArcEngine tools (i.e. being able to add a map to a windows form).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I can't find the ArcObjects SDK for Microsoft .Net Framework.  A Google search leads me nowhere.  This website: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/CPP_VB6_VBA_VCPP_Doc/shared/engine/get_started/install_reg_eng_sdk.htm makes me think that ArcGIS Desktop is enough, but does not lead me to the SDK at all.

Comment: See [this section of the ArcGIS for .NET help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/).

Comment: I guess they call it "ArcGIS Runtime" now.  http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/runtime

Comment: If you're developing for machines that already have ArcGIS Desktop installed, why not just create an Add-In? You can still create custom forms, but you won't have to worry about the basics of data display and other factors that are already built in to ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Yes, I believe what I want is ArcGIS Runtime.  I called ESRI and they had trouble remembering what it was called themselves...  This software needs to be deployable (without ArcGIS Desktop), so I cannot make an Add-In.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked, ArcGIS desktop license does not provide you a design time license for the [ArcGIS Engine TOC control](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00160000040r000000).   The [TOC control used by ArcMap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v000001r9000000) is not re-usable in a standalone exe.

You can use [RuntimeManager.InstalledRuntimes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/InstalledRuntimes_Property/004600000023000000/) to see what is installed on the machine, before initializing a license.  Since Engine licenses are less expensive than Desktop licenses, some enterprises would likely prefer your app to use an ArcEngine license if one is available - and only use a desktop license if no engine licenses are available.  The ArcGIS Visual Studio SDK have templates that use this sort of logic.  Not sure if the templates are only a part of the Engine SDK or are included in the ArcGIS for desktop SDK.  If you choose to develop with the desktop SDK, you will need to install it separately, but no additional license is required.

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing a standalone application you will require a ArcEngine runtime license on the users machine.  This is different to the Desktop license which will work if you're developing plugins for Esri tools.

It may be worth looking at the ArcGIS runtime SDK for WPF.  This is licensed differently and depending on the features you require, may not require your end user to require their own license.